# Disabling a input type problems

Tags: php

when I disable my date-picker input type when i echo the variable that has the values it doesn't show the correct data , appears 1970-01-01 but when i delete the disable tag from the input It starts working fine can you explain me why and help me solving this problem?

```
<html>
    <div class="two-col">
        <div class="col1">
            <label class="label1" style="font-size:20px" for="name"> Data de Cria&ccedil&atildeo</label>
            <input onkeypress="javascript:return false;" type="text" name="pdatacri" id="pdatacri" class="IP_calendar" title="Y-m-d" placeholder="Ano-Mes-Dia" value="<?php echo $datacri; ?>" style="width:200px;"> 
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <label class="label1" style="font-size:20px" for="name"> Data de Publica&ccedil&atildeo</label>
            <input onkeypress="javascript:return false;" type="text" name="pdatapub" id="pdatapub" alt="Data de Publicacao" class="IP_calendar" title="Y-m-d" placeholder="Ano-Mes-Dia" style="width:200px;" value="<?php echo $datapub; ?>"> 
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

PHP file

```
<?php
$datacri = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['pdatacri']);
$datacri = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $datacri)));
$datapub = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['pdatapub']);
$datapub = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $datapub)));

echo $datacri;
echo $datapub;
<?
```

If you need more code ask for it.
Thanks and have a nice day :)!

Comment: When you disable an HTML input element it does not get POSTed to the server

Comment: There's you answer  by @Andy

Comment: If the user is not supposed to change it, there is no reason to have an input at all. And you can keep the value on the server, for example in the session.

Comment: Any suggestion to solve this ?

Comment: Ok anyway I learned a new thing today thanks for the answer and sorry for the stupid question :)

Comment: Did you set up the DatePicker to use the fromat: `Y-m-d` that comes from php.

Comment: @Gonçalo there's no such thing as stupid question, the only stupid question is the question never asked... u a right by asking when u dont understand

Comment: Witch datepicker u use?

Comment: Well as you can see i had to use a different one because the data type doesn't work on safari/firefox/explorer so I used from this source <script type="text/javascript" src="http://services.iperfect.net/js/IP_generalLib.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling input, you should make it readonly

```
<input type='text' id='datepicker' name='fromdate' value='2017-01-01' readonly>
```

Comment: I've tried it and still changes the data with the date-picker

Comment: @Gonçalo can you try it with readonly='readonly' and see if it works?

Comment: Giving an element the attribute readonly will give that element the readonly status. It doesn't matter what value you put after it or if you put any value after it, it will still see it as readonly.